# Two consecutive adverbs: Why do you need to say "tout de suite mieux" rather than "mieux tout de suite"?

Tags: ordre-des-mots, adverbes

> On comprend **tout de suite mieux** pourquoi certaines personnes ne voudraient pas que ça se sache.
>
> On comprend **mieux tout de suite** pourquoi certaines personnes ne voudraient pas que ça se sache.

In an instance like this, I always wonder which of the two adverbs in a row I should place first before the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first adverb modifies the second one, so the two sentences have slightly different meanings.

> Mieux comprendre = to better understand
>
> On comprend mieux = one understands better
>
> On comprend tout de suite mieux = right away, one understands better

On the other hand:

> Comprendre tout de suite = to understand right away
>
> On comprend tout de suite = one understands right away
>
> On comprend mieux tout de suite = one understands better right away [than at another time]

With this sentence, "tout de suite mieux" is probably the one that makes sense, but here's another sentence in which the opposite would work:

> Dépêche-toi, ça se mange mieux tout de suite.
>
> Hurry up, it's better when you eat it right away.

Note putting the second adverb between commas can change the meaning. In such a situation the adverb might modify the entire sentence:

> On comprend mieux, tout de suite, pourquoi c'est arrivé.
>
> = Tout de suite, on comprend mieux pourquoi c'est arrivé.

Comment: Tout à fait, on pourrait aussi mettre *tout à fait* en fin de phrase / proposition  proposition après une virgule car il est important de noter aussi que l'adverbe peut aussi **modifier une phrase (ou proposition)** et pas seulement le mot (verbe, adverbe ou adjectif) juste à côté. Par contre when you say *mieux tout de suite après* you are not using *tout de suite* but *tout de suite après*, it's a different arrangement and you can't really compare it with just *tout de suite* when we know the length of an adverb (or locution adverbiale) has an influence on its place.

Comment: Merci, j'ai changé l'exemple pour éviter "tout de suite après".